# Unknown module(s) in QT: location-private positioning-private

Tags: qt, qtlocation, qtpositioning

how or where can i install QT modules: location-private positioning-private

`apt search positioning-private` does not have a result

Comment: What do you need the private interfaces for? I.e. what private APIs are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Just change version to match you environment:

```
    git clone https://github.com/qt/qtlocation.git
    cd qtlocation
    git checkout v5.11.3
    mkdir build
    cd build/
    qmake ../qtlocation.pro
    make -j4
    sudo make install
```

Source:
https://discuss.ardupilot.org/t/how-to-cross-compile-qgroundcontrol-for-raspberry-pi3/26790/42

Answer (score -2):

=> `apt install libqt5location5 libqt5positioning5` to get binaries

=> `apt install qtlocation5-dev qtpositioning5-dev` to get binaries with headers and development files

Comment: Already apt install these, but does not include location-private or positioning-private